# Get a field sum of subdocuments in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to get a sum of different currency amounts among multiple documents, but I'm struggling with the aggregation.

Initial documents (subdocuments are embedded, so no unwind is needed):

```
const products = [
  {
    title: 'product1',
    price: [
      {
        amount: 100,
        currency: 'USD',
      },
      {
        amount: 20,
        currency: 'EUR',
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'product2',
    price: [
      {
        amount: 330,
        currency: 'USD',
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    title: 'product3',
    price: [
      {
        amount: 50,
        currency: 'EUR',
      },
    ]
  },
];
```

Expected result:

```
const output = {
  grossIncome: [
    {
      amount: 430,
      currency: 'USD',
    },
    {
      amount: 70,
      currency: 'EUR',
    },
  ]
};
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need this aggregation query:

- First `$unwind` to deconstruct the array and can get each element.
- Then `$group` by currency and `$sum` the amount.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$price"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$price.currency",
      "amount": {
        "$sum": "$price.amount"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/okWVaggeXQG)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Seems like I was missing the `$unwind` step to make it work. Thank you so much!